# Best way to replace a special word in java

Tags: java, regex, string, for-loop, replace

In my current project, I have requirement to replace a word with a value in a paragraph.

Ex :

**"Event name is {[Event].[Name]}
Contact name is {[Contact].[Name]}"**

In the above line, '{[Event].[Name]}' should be replaced by the event name. The first part is an object (event). There are different objects. The second part (name) is a property of the object.

I have the Objects and relevant property values with me.

Can someone please tell me the best way to do this?

Should I use regex, a for loop or something else?

Comment: You probably need to use regex to extract the object/property name and then use reflection to find the matching values.

Comment: String interpolation??

Comment: Write a parser. Or use one regex for the curly braces and another regex for the square braces inside the curly braces and both in for loops. But that gets messy quickly as you extend your grammar

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
String.format("Event name is %s. Contact name is ‰s", event.getName(), contact.getName()) ;
```

If you need something more complex than that, use Velocity or FreeMarker templates

Answer (score 0):

a simple String `replace` (or two)

```
str = str.replace ("{[Event].", value1).replace ("[Name]}", value2);
```

Not sure if you wanted the `.` replaced or not

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should for for replacing it, but there is better ways to define the regex expression

```
String str = "Event name is {[Event].[Name]}";

String eventStr = "event";

String nameStr = "name";

str = str.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("{[Event].[Name]}"), String.format("%s.%s", eventStr, nameStr));
```